# Wrap an iterator to iterate over only some of the values

Tags: lua, iterator

I have a Lua iterator function that I don't have control over:

```lua
for x, y, z in otherfunc(stuff) do
   ...
end
```

I want to write a generic Lua wrapper to this function that skips over some of the values it returns, hiding this implementation detail from my users:

```lua
for x, y, z in myfunc(stuff) do
   -- not every x/y/z triplet will appear here
end
```

Though I happen to have three return values here, how can I handle this generically for any number of return values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local function check_and_return(my_state, x, ...)
   if x == nil or my_state[1](x, ...) then
      return x, ...
   else
      return check_and_return(my_state, my_state[2](my_state[3], x))
   end
end

local function my_generator(my_state, prev_x)
   return check_and_return(my_state, my_state[2](my_state[3], prev_x))
end

function subiterate(selector, generator, state, init_x)
   -- the iterator is stateless
   -- no closures created at loop initialization
   -- one table is created at loop initialization
   -- no tables created on every step
   return my_generator, {selector, generator, state}, init_x
end
```

Usage example:

```
local function everythird(i,_)
   return (i-1)%3==2
end

for i, n in subiterate(everythird, ipairs{'a','b','c','d','e','f'}) do
   print(i, n)
end
--> 3   c
--> 6   f
```

Comment: Smells real nice! One question: don't you need to pass more than `init_x` from subiterate? Theoretically couldn't the `generator` function want values beyond the first to help set its initial state?

Comment: @Phrogz - Lua passes only two arguments to generator.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific case of a known iterator function with specific number of return values, and a hard-coded selection criteria, I used this:

```lua
function myfunc(...)
   local generator, constant, x,y,z in otherfunc(...)
   return function()
      repeat x,y,z = generator(constant,x,y,z)
      until (not x) or x+y+z > 7
      if x then return x,y,z end
   end
end
```

The above will call the `otherfunc()` iterator repeatedly, but only yield x/y/z values when the sum of them is greater than 7.

More generically, here's a function that takes a selection function and an iterator, handling an arbitrary number of return values from the iterator and returning them only when the selector function returns a truthy value:

```lua
function subiterate(selector, generator, constant, ...)
   local values = {...}
   return function()
      repeat values = table.pack(generator(constant, table.unpack(values)))
      until not values[1] or selector(table.unpack(values))
      return table.unpack(values)
   end
end

local function everythird(i,_)
   return (i-1)%3==2
end

for i, n in subiterate(everythird, ipairs{'a','b','c','d','e','f'}) do
   print(i, n)
end
--> 3   c
--> 6   f
```

*I make no guarantees about the speed of the generic function, given all the `pack()` and `unpack()` going on. But it does work. I welcome any more efficient way to handle arbitrary numbers of return values for an iterator.*